# Append (html) delete?

Tags: jquery, append

I have a `div` that is created by Ajax with `.append(html)` function, 
 I'm trying to select that `div` and delete it, but I can't select it. How to select that `div` that is created dynamically by the .append() function?

**I created like this,**

```
 $("#loadplace"+Id).append(html);
```

**And I trying to delete like this;**

```
 $('#load_comment'+id).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
```

Comment: Show us the rest of your code, where is the id defined ?

Comment: Show the related HTML please.

Comment: Did the `id` variable change in the meantime?

Comment: rtaskiran.com/yardim.html you can look from here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#load_comment'+id).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).find("#myDiv").remove();});
```

Comment: I tried like this but I doesn't work,

`find('#load_comment'+id).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).find('#load_comment'+id).remove();});`

Comment: why `find('#load_comment'+id)` ? dont you have a div with only id inside ?

Comment: This main page that listing comments here,

gid = main page id

`<div id="loadplace<%=gid%>"></div>
<div id="flash<%=gid%>"></div>`

and this commenting page;

`$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "data/commentform.asp",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#loadplace"+Id).append(html);
$("#flash"+Id).hide();
$("textarea#textboxcontent"+Id).val('');
}
});
}return false;});`

and this append code that i sending this with ASP page

commentid = comment id veriable

`<div id='load_comment"&commentid&"'> COMMENT </div>`

Comment: gid is main page id and it's comments listing under to comments div. also I made new DIV that loadplace<%=gid%> for append comments. when I send comment then its adding inside to loadplace div.

Comment: wow... we have a lack of communication here... can you please post the full rendered code ? ( the part which is relevat,..)

Answer (score 0):

Try first with a variable:

```
var $myDiv = $(html);
```

then:

```
$("#loadplace"+Id).append($myDiv);
```

then:

```
$myDiv.remove();
```